# STL algorithm cannot access private member

Tags: c++

Apologize in advance for the amount of codes, but I can't find where the built error coming from.  This example built correctly on VC++ 6.0, but failed on the more recent compilers, including g++ and VC++ 2010.  The error message says error C2248: 'std::basic_ios<_Elem,_Traits>::basic_ios' : cannot access private member declared in class 'std::basic_ios<_Elem,_Traits>'  Help please.

```
  #pragma warning( disable : 4786 )  
  #pragma warning( disable : 4996 )  

  #include <iostream>
  #include <fstream>
  #include <algorithm>
  #include <vector>
  #include <list>
  #include <numeric>
  #include <iterator>

  template<class T>
  class Criteria {
  public:
    Criteria(T match) : m_match(match) {

    }

    bool operator()(T match) {
        return (m_match == match);
    }
  private:
    T m_match;
  };

  template<class T>
  class BinaryCriteria {
  public:
    bool operator()(T item1, T item2) {
        return (item1*item1 > item2+item2);
    }
  };

  std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& o, std::string rhs) {
    return (o << rhs.c_str());
  }

  void print( int x ) {
    std::cout << x << " ";
  }

  template<class T>
  class Print {
  public:
    Print(const char* sep) : m_sep(sep) {
    }
    void operator()(T item) {
        std::cout << item << m_sep.c_str();
    }
  private:
    std::string m_sep;
  };

  template<class T>
  class Equal {
  public:

    bool operator()(T item1, T item2) {
        return (item1 * 2 == item2);
    }
  };

  template<class T>
  class File {
  public:
    File(const char* file) {
        m_in.open(file);
    }
    ~File() {
        if (m_in)
            m_in.close();
    }
    T operator()() {
        m_in.getline(m_buf, sizeof(m_buf));
        T line = m_buf;
        return line;
    }
  private:
    std::ifstream m_in;
    char m_buf[80];
  };

  template<class T>
  class Odd {
  public:
    bool operator()(T item) {
        if (item % 2 != 0)
            return false;
        else
            return true;
    }
  };

  template<class T>
  class Upper {
  public:
    T operator()(T item) {
        std::transform(item.begin(),item.end(),item.begin(),::toupper);
        return item;
    }
  };

  template<class T>
  class Concat {
  public:
    Concat(const char* sep) : m_sep(sep) {

    }
    T operator()(T item1, T item2) {
        T out;
        out = item1;
        out += m_sep;
        out += item2;
        return out;
    }
  private:
    std::string m_sep;
  };

  template<class T>
  class TheSame {
  public:
    bool operator()(T item1, T item2) {
        if (item1 * 10 == item2)
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }
  };

  template<class T>
  class Rand {
  public:
    T operator()() {
        return static_cast<T>(::rand());
    }
  };

  struct Employee {
    Employee(std::string name, std::string dept, std::string id) :
          m_name(name), m_dept(dept), m_id(id) {
    }
    std::string m_name;
    std::string m_dept;
    std::string m_id;
  };

  class SortByName {
  public:
    bool operator()(const Employee* lhs, const Employee* rhs) {
        int res = ::strcmp(lhs->m_name.c_str(),rhs->m_name.c_str());
        if (res == -1)
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }
  };

  class SortByDept {
  public:
    bool operator()(const Employee* lhs, const Employee* rhs) {
        int res = ::strcmp(lhs->m_dept.c_str(),rhs->m_dept.c_str());
        if (res == -1)
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }
  };

  class SortById {
  public:
    bool operator()(const Employee* lhs, const Employee* rhs) {
        int res = ::strcmp(lhs->m_id.c_str(),rhs->m_id.c_str());
        if (res == -1)
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }
  };

  std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& o, const Employee* rhs) {
    o << rhs->m_name << "," << rhs->m_dept << "," << rhs->m_id;
    return o;
  }

  int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {

  if (false)    {

            std::vector<int> v;
            for (int i=0; i<10; i++)
                v.push_back(i);

            std::vector<int>::iterator ifind = std::find(v.begin(), v.end(), -4);
            if (ifind != v.end())
                std::cout << "Item found " << *ifind << std::endl;
            else 
                std::cout << "Item was not found" << std::endl;

            ifind = std::find_if(v.begin(), v.end(), Criteria<int>(4));
            if (ifind != v.end())
                std::cout << "Item found " << *ifind << std::endl;
            else 
                std::cout << "Item was not found" << std::endl;
    }

  if (false)    {

            std::vector<int> v;
            for (int i=0; i<10; i++)
                v.push_back(i);
            v[4] = 5; // create an adjacent pair

            std::vector<int>::iterator ifind = std::adjacent_find(v.begin(), v.end());
            if (ifind != v.end())
                std::cout << "Items found " << *ifind << " " << *(ifind+1) << std::endl;
            else 
                std::cout << "Items were not found" << std::endl;

            v[4] = 4; // create an adjacent pair
            ifind = std::adjacent_find(v.begin(), v.end(), BinaryCriteria<int>());
            if (ifind != v.end())
                std::cout << "Items found " << *ifind << " " << *(ifind+1) << std::endl;
            else 
                std::cout << "Items were not found" << std::endl;
    }

  if (false)    {

            std::vector<int> v;
            for (int i=0; i<10; i++)
                v.push_back(i);
            v[3] = 3;
            v[7] = 3; // some duplicates

            std::cout << "The item " << 2 << " appears " 
                      << std::count( v.begin(), v.end(), 2) 
                      << " times" << std::endl;

            std::cout << "The item " << 3 << " appears " 
                      << std::count_if( v.begin(), v.end(), Criteria<int>(3)) 
                      << " times" << std::endl;

    }

  if (false)    {

            std::vector<int> v;
            for (int i=0; i<10; i++)
                v.push_back(i);

            std::for_each(v.begin(), v.end(), Print<int>(" "));
            std::cout << std::endl;
            std::for_each(v.begin(), v.end(), print);
            std::cout << std::endl;
    }   

  if (false)    {

            std::vector<int> v;
            for (int i=0; i<10; i++)
                v.push_back(i);
            int tab[3] = { 0, 1, 2 };

            bool res = std::equal(tab, tab+3, v.begin());
            if (res)
                std::cout << "Ranges are equal" << std::endl;
            else
                std::cout << "Ranges are not equal" << std::endl;


            v[0] = 2 * tab[0];
            v[1] = 2 * tab[1];
            v[2] = 2 * tab[2];
            res = std::equal(tab, tab+3, v.begin(), Equal<int>());
            if (res)
                std::cout << "Ranges are equal" << std::endl;
            else
                std::cout << "Ranges are not equal" << std::endl;

            res = std::equal(tab, tab+3, v.begin());
            if (res)
                std::cout << "Ranges are equal" << std::endl;
            else
                std::cout << "Ranges are not equal" << std::endl;

            res = std::equal(tab, tab+3, &v[5], Equal<int>());
            if (res)
                std::cout << "Ranges are equal" << std::endl;
            else
                std::cout << "Ranges are not equal" << std::endl;

    }   

  if (false)    {

            std::vector<int> v;
            for (int i=0; i<10; i++)
                v.push_back(i);
            int tab[6] = { 0, 1, 2, 4, 5, 6 };

            std::pair<int*, std::vector<int>::iterator> res =
                std::mismatch(tab, tab+6, v.begin() );
            if (res.first != (tab+6)) {
                std::cout << "mismatch located " 
                    << "item in first range " << *res.first <<
                       " item in second range " << *res.second << std::endl;
            } else
                std::cout << "No mismatch found within the range" << std::endl;

            v[0] = 2 * tab[0];
            v[1] = 2 * tab[1];
            v[2] = 2 * tab[2];
            tab[3] = -99;
            res = std::mismatch(tab, tab+6, v.begin(), Equal<int>() );
            if (res.first != (tab+6)) {
                std::cout << "mismatch located " 
                    << "item in first range " << *res.first <<
                       " item in second range " << *res.second << std::endl;
            } else
                std::cout << "No mismatch found within the range" << std::endl;

    }   

  if (false)    {

            std::vector<int> v;
            for (int i=0; i<10; i++)
                v.push_back(i);
            int tab[3] = { 4, 5, 6 };

            std::vector<int>::iterator res = std::search(v.begin(), v.end(), tab, tab+3);
            if (res != v.end())
                std::cout << "Subsequence located - first item = " << *res << std::endl;
            else
                std::cout << "Subsequence not located" << std::endl;

            tab[0] = 2 * v[5];
            tab[1] = 2 * v[6];
            tab[2] = 2 * v[7];
            // predicate function version
            res = std::search(v.begin(), v.end(), tab, tab+3, Equal<int>());
            if (res != v.end())
                std::cout << "Subsequence located - first item = " << *res << std::endl;
            else
                std::cout << "Subsequence not located" << std::endl;

    }

  if (false)    {

            std::vector<int> v(10);
            int tab[10] = { 10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90, 100 };
            std::copy(tab,tab+10,v.begin());
            std::for_each(v.begin(),v.end(),Print<int>(" "));
            std::cout << std::endl;

            std::copy_backward(tab,tab+10,v.end());
            std::for_each(v.begin(),v.end(),Print<int>(" "));
            std::cout << std::endl;

            std::vector<char> v2;
            const char* str = "ABCDEFGHIJ";
            std::copy(str,str+10,std::back_inserter(v2));

            std::cout << "Before shift left" << std::endl;
            std::for_each(v2.begin(),v2.end(),Print<char>(""));
            std::cout << std::endl;

            std::copy(v2.begin()+1, v2.end(), v2.begin());

            std::cout << "After shift left" << std::endl;
            std::for_each(v2.begin(),v2.end(),Print<char>(""));
            std::cout << std::endl;

            std::copy(str,str+10,v2.begin());

            std::cout << "Before shift right" << std::endl;
            std::for_each(v2.begin(),v2.end(),Print<char>(""));
            std::cout << std::endl;

            std::copy_backward(v2.begin(), v2.end()-1, v2.end());

            std::cout << "After shift right" << std::endl;
            std::for_each(v2.begin(),v2.end(),Print<char>(""));
            std::cout << std::endl;

    }

  if (false)    {

            std::vector<int> v(10);
            std::fill(v.begin(),v.end(),-5);
            std::for_each(v.begin(),v.end(),Print<int>(" "));
            std::cout << std::endl;

            std::fill_n(v.begin(),10,-5);
            std::for_each(v.begin(),v.end(),Print<int>(" "));
            std::cout << std::endl;

    }

  if (false)    {

            std::vector<std::string> v(10);

            std::generate(v.begin(),v.end(),File<std::string>("c:/temp/items.txt"));
            std::for_each(v.begin(),v.end(),Print<std::string>("\n"));
            std::cout << std::endl;

    }

  if (false)    {
            std::vector<int> v;
            for(int i=0; i<10; i++)
                v.push_back(i);
            std::vector<int>::iterator res =
                std::partition(v.begin(),v.end(),Odd<int>());

            // display each range
            std::cout << "first range ";
            std::for_each(v.begin(),res,Print<int>(" "));
            std::cout << std::endl;

            std::cout << "second range ";
            std::for_each(res,v.end(),Print<int>(" "));
            std::cout << std::endl;

            // repeat for stable_partition
            for(int i=0; i<10; i++)
                v[i]=i;
            res = std::stable_partition(v.begin(),v.end(),Odd<int>());

            // display each range
            std::cout << "first range ";
            std::for_each(v.begin(),res,Print<int>(" "));
            std::cout << std::endl;

            std::cout << "second range ";
            std::for_each(res,v.end(),Print<int>(" "));
            std::cout << std::endl;

            // repeat using STL components
            for(int i=0; i<10; i++)
                v[i]=i;
            res = std::partition(v.begin(),v.end(),
                std::bind2nd(  std::greater<int>(),  2));

            // display each range
            std::cout << "first range ";
            std::for_each(v.begin(),res,Print<int>(" "));
            std::cout << std::endl;

            std::cout << "second range ";
            std::for_each(res,v.end(),Print<int>(" "));
            std::cout << std::endl;

            // repeat using STL components
            for(int i=0; i<10; i++)
                v[i]=i;
            res = std::partition(v.begin(),v.end(),
                std::bind1st(  std::greater<int>(),  2));

            // display each range
            std::cout << "first range ";
            std::for_each(v.begin(),res,Print<int>(" "));
            std::cout << std::endl;

            std::cout << "second range ";
            std::for_each(res,v.end(),Print<int>(" "));
            std::cout << std::endl;

    }

  if (false)    {
            // random_shuffle randomly rearranges the items in a range.
            std::vector<int> v;
            for(int i=0; i<100; i++)
                v.push_back(i);
            std::random_shuffle(v.begin(),v.end());
            std::copy(v.begin(),v.end(),
                std::ostream_iterator<int>(std::cout," "));
            std::cout << std::endl;

    }

  if (false)    {
            int buf[10] = { 2, 5, 3, 5, 4, 5, 6, 6, 5, 5 };

            int* res = std::remove(buf, buf+10, 5);

            std::cout << "items to keep ";
            std::copy(buf, res, std::ostream_iterator<int>(std::cout," "));
            std::cout << std::endl;

            std::cout << "items to remove ";
            std::copy(res, buf+10, std::ostream_iterator<int>(std::cout," "));
            std::cout << std::endl;

            // test with vector
            std::vector<int> v;
            for(int i=0; i<10; i++)
                v.push_back(i);

            std::cout << "size of v before call to remove " << v.size() << std::endl;
            std::vector<int>::iterator p = std::remove(v.begin(), v.end(), 5);
            std::cout << "size of v after call to remove " << v.size() << std::endl;

            v.erase(p);
            std::cout << "size of v after erase " << v.size() << std::endl;
            std::copy(v.begin(), v.end(), std::ostream_iterator<int>(std::cout," "));
            std::cout << std::endl;

    }

  if (false)    {
            int buf[10] = { 2, 5, 3, 5, 4, 5, 6, 6, 5, 5 };
            std::copy(buf, buf+10, std::ostream_iterator<int>(std::cout," "));
            std::cout << std::endl;
            std::replace(buf, buf+10, 5, 0);
            std::copy(buf, buf+10, std::ostream_iterator<int>(std::cout," "));
            std::cout << std::endl;

    }

  if (false)    {
            // The reverse algorithm reverses the order of the items in a given range.
            int buf[10] = { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 };

            std::cout << "Before reverse ";
            std::copy(buf, buf+10, std::ostream_iterator<int>(std::cout," "));
            std::cout << std::endl;

            std::reverse(buf, buf+10);

            std::cout << "After reverse ";
            std::copy(buf, buf+10, std::ostream_iterator<int>(std::cout," "));
            std::cout << std::endl;

    }

  if (false)    {
            int buf[10] = { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 };

            std::cout << "Before rotate ";
            std::copy(buf, buf+10, std::ostream_iterator<int>(std::cout," "));
            std::cout << std::endl;

            std::rotate(buf, buf+4, buf+10);

            std::cout << "After rotate ";
            std::copy(buf, buf+10, std::ostream_iterator<int>(std::cout," "));
            std::cout << std::endl;

    }

  if (false)    {
            // The swap function swaps to values
            std::string first="Hello";
            std::string second="World";
            std::cout << first << " " << second << std::endl;
            std::swap(first,second);
            std::cout << first << " " << second << std::endl;

            // The swap_ranges function swaps ranges.
            std::list<std::string> ll;
            ll.push_front("Homer");
            ll.push_front("Marge");
            ll.push_front("Bart");

            std::vector<std::string> vec;
            vec.push_back("Moe");
            vec.push_back("Wiggum");
            vec.push_back("Burns");

            std::swap_ranges(ll.begin(),ll.end(),vec.begin());

            std::cout << "List values ";
            std::for_each(ll.begin(),ll.end(),Print<std::string>(" "));
            std::cout << std::endl;

            std::cout << "Vector values ";
            std::for_each(vec.begin(),vec.end(),Print<std::string>(" "));
            std::cout << std::endl;

    }

  if (false)    {
            std::vector<std::string> v(3);
            std::list<std::string> ll;
            ll.push_front("Homer");
            ll.push_front("Marge");
            ll.push_front("Bart");
            std::transform(ll.begin(),ll.end(),v.begin(),Upper<std::string>());
            std::cout << "Uppercase names ";
            std::for_each(v.begin(),v.end(),Print<std::string>(" "));
            std::cout << std::endl;

            std::list<std::string> ll2;
            ll2.push_front("Simpson");
            ll2.push_front("Simpson");
            ll2.push_front("Simpson");
            std::transform(ll.begin(),ll.end(),ll2.begin(),v.begin(),Concat<std::string>(" "));
            std::cout << "Concat'ed names ";
            std::for_each(v.begin(),v.end(),Print<std::string>("\n"));
            std::cout << std::endl;

            int a[10] = { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 };
            int b[10] = { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 };
            int c[10];
            std::transform(a,a+10,b,c,std::plus<int>());
            std::for_each(c,c+10,Print<int>(" "));
            std::cout << std::endl;

            std::transform(a,a+10,c,std::bind2nd(std::plus<int>(),10));
            std::for_each(c,c+10,Print<int>(" "));
            std::cout << std::endl;


    }

  if (false)    {
            int tab[10] = { 1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 4, 5, 6, 6, 7 };
            int* res = std::unique(tab, tab+10);

            std::cout << "Unique items ";
            std::for_each(tab,res,Print<int>(" "));
            std::cout << std::endl;

            // Binary predicate function version.
            int tab2[10] = { 1, 2, 20, 3, 4, 40, 5, 6, 60, 7 };
            res = std::unique(tab2, tab2+10, TheSame<int>());

            std::cout << "Unique items ";
            std::for_each(tab2,res,Print<int>(" "));
            std::cout << std::endl;

            int tab3[10] = { 1, 2, 20, 3, 4, 40, 5, 6, 60, 7 };
            res = std::unique(tab3, tab3+10);

            std::cout << "Unique items ";
            std::for_each(tab3,res,Print<int>(" "));
            std::cout << std::endl;

    }

  if (false)    {

            int tab[10];

            // initialize
            std::generate(tab,tab+10,Rand<int>());

            std::cout << "Unsorted sequence ";
            std::for_each(tab,tab+10,Print<int>(" "));
            std::cout << std::endl;

            std::sort(tab,tab+10,std::less<int>());

            std::cout << "Sorted ascending order sequence ";
            std::for_each(tab,tab+10,Print<int>(" "));
            std::cout << std::endl;

            // initialize
            std::generate(tab,tab+10,Rand<int>());

            std::cout << "Unsorted sequence ";
            std::for_each(tab,tab+10,Print<int>(" "));
            std::cout << std::endl;

            std::sort(tab,tab+10,std::greater<int>());

            std::cout << "Sorted descending order sequence ";
            std::for_each(tab,tab+10,Print<int>(" "));
            std::cout << std::endl;

            // customize the sort criteria
            std::vector<Employee*> v;
            v.push_back( new Employee("EEE", "Dept AAA", "Id100") );
            v.push_back( new Employee("CCC", "Dept BBB", "Id500") );
            v.push_back( new Employee("BBB", "Dept DDD", "Id300") );
            v.push_back( new Employee("FFF", "Dept CCC", "Id600") );
            v.push_back( new Employee("AAA", "Dept CCC", "Id200") );
            v.push_back( new Employee("DDD", "Dept AAA", "Id000") );

            std::cout << "Unsorted employees " << std::endl;
            std::for_each(v.begin(),v.end(),Print<Employee*>("\n"));
            std::cout << std::endl;

            // sort by name
            std::sort(v.begin(),v.end(),SortByName());

            std::cout << "Sorted employees by name " << std::endl;
            std::for_each(v.begin(),v.end(),Print<Employee*>("\n"));
            std::cout << std::endl;

            // sort by id
            std::sort(v.begin(),v.end(),SortById());

            std::cout << "Sorted employees by id " << std::endl;
            std::for_each(v.begin(),v.end(),Print<Employee*>("\n"));
            std::cout << std::endl;

            // sort by dept
            std::sort(v.begin(),v.end(),SortByDept());

            std::cout << "Sorted employees by dept " << std::endl;
            std::for_each(v.begin(),v.end(),Print<Employee*>("\n"));
            std::cout << std::endl;


            // sort by name, the by dept
            std::sort(v.begin(),v.end(),SortByName());
            std::stable_sort(v.begin(),v.end(),SortByDept());
            std::cout << "Sorted employees by name then stable sorted by dept " << std::endl;
            std::for_each(v.begin(),v.end(),Print<Employee*>("\n"));
            std::cout << std::endl;


            // initialize
            std::generate(tab,tab+10,Rand<int>());

            std::cout << "Unsorted sequence " << std::endl;
            std::for_each(tab,tab+10,Print<int>(" "));
            std::cout << std::endl;

            std::partial_sort(tab,tab+3,tab+10,std::greater<int>());

            std::cout << "Partially sorted (top 3) in descending order sequence " << std::endl;
            std::for_each(tab,tab+10,Print<int>(" "));
            std::cout << std::endl;

            double salaries[10] = { 22000.0, 28500.00, 17500.00, 22000.0, 54000.00,
                77500.00, 18400.00, 100000.00, 23000.0, 50000.0 };
            std::nth_element(salaries, salaries+2, salaries+10, std::less<double>());
            std::cout << "The 3rd top salary is " << salaries[2] << std::endl;
            std::cout << std::endl;

            }

  if (false)    {

            std::vector<int> keys;
            for (int i=0; i<100; i++)
                keys.push_back(i);
            std::sort(keys.begin(), keys.end(), std::less<int>());

            // is item 55 in the sequence?
            bool isThere = std::binary_search(keys.begin(), keys.end(), int(55));
            if (isThere)
                std::cout << "The key 55 is in the sequence" << std::endl;
            else
                std::cout << "The key 55 is not in the sequence" << std::endl;

            // is item 555 in the sequence?
            isThere = std::binary_search(keys.begin(), keys.end(), int(555));
            if (isThere)
                std::cout << "The key 555 is in the sequence" << std::endl;
            else
                std::cout << "The key 555 is not in the sequence" << std::endl;

            }

  if (false)    {

            std::list<float> ll;
            ll.push_front(70.0f);
            ll.push_front(60.0f);
            ll.push_front(50.0f);
            ll.push_front(30.0f);
            ll.push_front(20.0f);
            ll.push_front(10.0f);
            std::list<float>::iterator iter = 
                std::lower_bound(ll.begin(), ll.end(), 40.0f);
            ll.insert(iter, 40.0f);
            std::for_each(ll.begin(), ll.end(), Print<float>(" "));
            std::cout << std::endl;

            std::list<float> ll2;
            ll2.push_front(70.0f);
            ll2.push_front(60.0f);
            ll2.push_front(50.0f);
            ll2.push_front(30.0f);
            ll2.push_front(20.0f);
            ll2.push_front(10.0f);
            std::list<float>::iterator iter2 = 
                std::upper_bound(ll2.begin(), ll2.end(), 40.0f);
            ll2.insert(iter2, 40.0f);
            std::for_each(ll2.begin(), ll2.end(), Print<float>(" "));
            std::cout << std::endl;

            std::list<float> ll3;
            ll3.push_front(70.0f);
            ll3.push_front(60.0f);
            ll3.push_front(50.0f);
            ll3.push_front(30.0f);
            ll3.push_front(20.0f);
            ll3.push_front(10.0f);
            std::pair< std::list<float>::iterator, std::list<float>::iterator > res =
                std::equal_range(ll3.begin(), ll3.end(), 40.0f);
            std::cout << *res.first << " " << *res.second << std::endl;
            std::cout << std::endl;

            }


  if (false)    {
        int tab1[5] = { 10, 20, 30, 40, 50 };
        int tab2[5] = { 5, 15, 25, 35, 45 };
        int tab3[10];
        std::merge(tab1,tab1+5,tab2,tab2+5,tab3);
        std::cout << "The merged list ";
        std::for_each(tab3,tab3+10,Print<int>(" "));
        std::cout << std::endl;

        int tab4[10] = { 10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 5, 15, 25, 35, 45 };
        std::inplace_merge(tab4,tab4+5,tab4+10);
        std::cout << "The in-place merged list ";
        std::for_each(tab4,tab4+10,Print<int>(" "));
        std::cout << std::endl;

    }

  if (false)    {
        // The set algorithms allows set operations on sorted sequences.
        int tab1[5] = { 10, 20, 30, 40, 50 };
        int tab2[5] = { 10, 25, 30, 45, 50 };
        int tab3[10];

        // union
        int* p = std::set_union(tab1,tab1+5,tab2,tab2+5,tab3);
        std::cout << "Union ";
        std::for_each(tab3,p,Print<int>(" "));
        std::cout << std::endl;

        // intersection
        p = std::set_intersection(tab1,tab1+5,tab2,tab2+5,tab3);
        std::cout << "Intersection ";
        std::for_each(tab3,p,Print<int>(" "));
        std::cout << std::endl;

        // difference
        p = std::set_difference(tab1,tab1+5,tab2,tab2+5,tab3);
        std::cout << "Difference ";
        std::for_each(tab3,p,Print<int>(" "));
        std::cout << std::endl;

        // symmetric difference
        p = std::set_symmetric_difference(tab1,tab1+5,tab2,tab2+5,tab3);
        std::cout << "Symmetric difference ";
        std::for_each(tab3,p,Print<int>(" "));
        std::cout << std::endl;

        int tab4[3] = { 20, 30, 40 };
        bool res = std::includes(tab1,tab1+5,tab4,tab4+3);
        if (res)
            std::cout << "Located the sequence in tab4 within tab1" << std::endl;
        else
            std::cout << "The sequence in tab4 is not located within tab1" << std::endl;

    }

  if (true) {

        int tab[10] = { 2, 4, 6, 1, 3, 5, 8, 7, 9, 100 };
        int* p = std::min_element(tab,tab+10);
        std::cout << "Min value = " << *p << std::endl;

        p = std::max_element(tab,tab+10);
        std::cout << "Max value = " << *p << std::endl;

    }



    return 0;
  }
```

Comment: Too much code. Not [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: I understand it is too much code, but just paste the code into an IDE and one should see the error.  It is the build error I am after, not the codes.  Thanks.

Comment: Actually, you should post just the line that's giving the error and some information that you find relevant. That's a lot of code.

Comment: The error was found in the fstream header file.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your problem is that you're creating an instance of your File object and passing it to `std::generate` (around line 405). A `File` contains an instance of `std::ifstream`, and the functor is passed to `std::generate` by value, which means it receives a copy of the original object -- but since this object contains a `std::ifstream`, which can't be copied, that won't work.

As to how you find this: start by using an `#if 0` to disable all your `if (false)` sections, and you'll find that it compiles and runs just fine.

From there, use bisection: enable half of them by moving the `#if 0` down to (around) the middle of that huge block (and just before one of the `if (false)` lines). See if it still compiles. If it does, move the `#if 0` down to about 3/4<sup>ths</sup> of the way down that section. If not, move it up to about 1/4<sup>th</sup> of the way through that chunk (and each time, assuring it's just before an `if (false)`). With a few iterations, you'll narrow it down to a single `` `if (false) `` chunk (that, in this case, is only 5 lines long). When it's that small, it's probably easiest to just look at the problem code.

Comment: Yes, I got the same results.  Is there a way to passed to std::generate by reference, if there is, will you show me how to do this.  Thanks.

Comment: @ZzzZz: You can't make `std::generate` accept an argument by reference. The obvious thing to do would be to prevent `File` from being copied at all. If you can't change the code, you might want to consider a TR1/C++11 `reference_wrapper`. I haven't tried it, but suspect that stands at least a decent chance of letting the code compile.

Answer (score 9):

Your post does not include a question. I will assume that you would have asked "What does this error message mean?"

The answer to *that* question is: `std::ifstream` is not copyable.

Comment: ok. I accept, but why is this code can built correctly under VC++ 6.0 ?  Thanks.

Comment: The code is incorrect. Perhaps it can be built under VC++6.0, but it cannot, by definition, be built *correctly* under VC++ 6.0.

Comment: @ZzzZz: the standard says that `class basic_ios<>` should have  private, undefined copy ctor and assignment operator, making the class uncopyable (and `class ifstream<>` indirectly inherits `base_ios`, making `ifstream` also uncopyable). VC++6 doesn't do that.

Comment: Is there a general quick "conversion" fix for these sort of things.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The error is coming from line 407.

```
std::generate(v.begin(),v.end(),File<std::string>("c:/temp/items.txt"));
```

Which is stemming from the creation of your File object (defined earlier in the program). Now, if I understand what this line is doing correctly, you are populating the vector with each line of the fine (since the () operator constantly returns a line via the getline() function from the opened file). If you replace the following if block

```
if (false)    {

        std::vector<std::string> v(10);

        std::generate(v.begin(),v.end(),File<std::string>("c:/temp/items.txt"));
        std::for_each(v.begin(),v.end(),Print<std::string>("\n"));
        std::cout << std::endl;

}
```

With this block

```
if (false)    {
        std::vector<std::string> v;
        std::ifstream fi("c:/temp/items.txt");
        std::string line;

        while (!fi.eof ()) {
            getline (fi, line);
            v.push_back (line);
        }
        fi.close();

        std::for_each(v.begin(),v.end(),Print<std::string>("\n"));
        std::cout << std::endl;
}
```

Your program should run as expected, when you turn that if (false) to an if (true).

Also, you may want to include cstring, because you reference strcmp, which (at least for g++) needs the cstring header file.

Comment: my code failed at getline (fi, line), please advice the full qualifier for getline, as it was not in std::getline, and not in fstream::getline.  Thanks.

Comment: It is the getline in istream, with a signature of: `istream& getline(istream& is, string& str)` You can read about it, and see an example here: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/getline/

Comment: I tried including the #include <string>, and it compiled, but I got the error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _wWinMain@16 referenced in function ___tmainCRTStartup  error, any idea why ?  thanks.

Comment: That is caused by attempting to compile a program as Windows without having a `WinMain()` function. Since you have a `main()`, you are attempting to compile it as a console application. If you're using Visual Studios (this may be slightly different depending on the edition, but in VS2010, do this) Open your project, go to `Project -> Properties`, select `Configuration Properties -> Linker -> System` then under `SubSystem` change it from `Windows (/SUBSYSTEM:WINDOWS)` to `Console (/SUBSYSTEM:CONSOLE)`